# android navigation pass arguments to fragment constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have created Navigation Drawer Activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

And I have `mobile_navigation.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/databaseFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/databaseFragment"
        android:name="com.acmpo6ou.myaccounts.ui.DatabaseFragment"
        android:label="fragment_database_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_database_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionCreateDatabase"
            app:destination="@id/createDatabaseFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/createDatabaseFragment"
        android:name="com.acmpo6ou.myaccounts.ui.CreateDatabaseFragment"
        android:label="create_edit_database_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/create_edit_database_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

The start destination is `DatabaseFragment`. However there is a problem, here is my `DatabaseFragment`:

```kotlin
class DatabaseFragment(
        override val adapter: DatabasesAdapterInter,
        val presenter: DatabasesPresenterInter
) : Fragment(), DatabaseFragmentInter {
...
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(
                adapter: DatabasesAdapterInter,
                presenter: DatabasesPresenterInter
        ) = DatabaseFragment(adapter, presenter)
    }
}
```

As you can see my `DatabaseFragment` should receive two arguments to its constructor: `adapter` and `presenter`. This is because of dependency injection, in my tests I can instantiate `DatabaseFragment` passing through mocked `adapter` and `presenter`. Like this:

```kotlin
...
val adapter = mock<DatabasesAdapterInter>()
val presenter = mock<DatabasesPresenterInter>()
val fragment = DatabaseFragment(adapter, presenter)
...
```

It works with tests, but it doesn't work with android navigation. It seems that Android Navigation Components create `DatabaseFragment` instead of me, but they don't pass any arguments to fragment's constructor and it fails with error that is too long to post it here.

Is there a way to tell Navigation Components so that they pass appropriate arguments to my fragments when instantiating them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, you can not pass arguments to `Fragment`.

All subclasses of `Fragment` must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So there is no way? But what should I do? Maybe I could somehow use safeargs or something?

Comment: You should use `dependency injection` framework like `Dagger2` or `Hilt` and inject your dependency into fields.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to i30mb1 answer:

Is there really a necessity for you to pass those two arguments in the constructor?

- As far as I know and as far as I have experimented with MVP, each view should have a presenter. So for example when I create a new fragment, I create a new presenter for it. Then the parent activity should have another presenter. If you need that presenter so that the fragment can make changes in the Activities view, you could implement interfaces, but that's another topic.
- If you ever need to pass simple arguments using navigation like POJOS or even simplier objects like Strings etc.. you can use SafeArgs https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Answer (score 0):

I fixed everything pretty easily using default arguments, like this:

```kotlin
class DatabaseFragment(
        override val adapter: DatabasesAdapterInter = DatabasesAdapter(),
        val presenter: DatabasesPresenterInter = DatabasesPresenter()
) : Fragment(), DatabaseFragmentInter {
...
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = DatabaseFragment()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Then there's no need to declare them in the constructor. You can declare those as fields and that's it. Perfect !